# Is it grammatical to say "It's much more cheaper. . ."?

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison, intensifiers

I was confused when I corrected my student and he asked me if he could use "much more" in a sentence. I'm used to using "much" and "more" separately that's why I didn't know what to say.

Answer (score 1):

"Much more" is fine, but it can't be combined with another comparative adjective like "cheaper." "More" is usually used with adverbs or with adjectives that don't have a comparative form. "Much" can be paired with either form.

> - It's much cheaper.
> - It's much more effective. ("More" because "effective" doesn't have a comparative form.)
> - It's much more fast. (Grammatical, but unusual since we'd usually use the comparative form: "It's much faster.")

Comment: "The teddy bear is much more cheaper than the teddy bear."

Should it be "The teddy bear is much cheaper than the teddy bear"?

Comment: @chell Yes, that's right.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant ""The teddy bear is much cheaper than the computer". Thank you so much for replying! It helped a lot!

Comment: @chell You can also say *it's much more cheap*. (Although it's not as common or idiomatic.)